# How to use jquery .on() with jquery plugins(for eg with hoverpulse)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-hover, jquery-on

I am trying using .on() with hoverpulse plugin for applying it to dynamically loaded contents but not getting a way out.
It will be very kind if someone can help.
Thanks in advance.

JQUERY CODE TO CALL HOVERPULSE FUNCTION

```
$(selector).hoverpulse({

    size: 40,  // number of pixels to pulse element (in each direction)
    speed: 400 // speed of the animation 
})
```

HOVERPULSE FUNCTION

```
$.fn.hoverpulse = function(options) { CODE GOES HERE}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `on` syntax is for event binding/handling. Not for plugins..

Comment: Then how to apply hoverpulse to contents that are being dynamically loaded using ajax or getJSON of jquery

Comment: @Abhinav, run the `.hoverpulse()` from the callback  function of the ajax/getJSON call.